# Update from 1.4.0.1 to 1.6.1 via full package update

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.4

I got to the final point where I call some page in my shop. I believe all the database updates were done, now the applyUpdates() method is being called, but the following error appears:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Core_Helper_Data::useDbCompatibleMode() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php on line 308

The mentioned method is in the `Mage_Core_Helper_Data` class, so it seems as the system doesn't see the whole class.

Have no clue where to go from here, any help would be significant.

Answer (score 1):

Check out these points :

1. Does the `Mage_Core_Helper_Data` class file exists ? This file should be in `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper` and the file is `Data.php`.
2. Is it readable by the user who executes PHP ?

If not, try setting proper permissions on your files, they may have been altered during the update.

Comment: Yes, the class is there, the method's in there, and I set all files to 777 mode, but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was an old `app/code/local/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php`.

Check if `app/code/local/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php` exists and delete it or merge with `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php`.